# Can I use classes instead of all these if statements? Discord python bot

Tags: python, class, bots, discord

I have this question about classes/if statements.

I have this code with a lot of `if` statements that looks like this:

```
if message.content.lower().startswith("test"):
        time.sleep(1)
        await message.add_reaction(gEmoji)
        await message.add_reaction(aEmoji)
        await message.add_reaction(yEmoji)
```

But all for different words and emojis.

This is my short version of my code:

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import sys
import os
import cogs
import config
import logging
import asyncio
import datetime
import time

client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='*')

gEmoji = ""
aEmoji = ""
yEmoji = ""

hEmoji = ""
oEmoji = ""
tEmoji = ""

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith("test"):
        time.sleep(1)
        await message.add_reaction(gEmoji)
        await message.add_reaction(aEmoji)
        await message.add_reaction(yEmoji)

    if message.content.startswith("hot"):
        time.sleep(1)
        await message.add_reaction(hEmoji)
        await message.add_reaction(oEmoji)
        await message.add_reaction(tEmoji)


client.run("TOKEN/CENSORED")
```

In my version of this code I have ~200 lines of code and ~150 of them are only `if` statements.

As I'm new to Python and just started using classes, I was wondering if somehow I can change the if statements to use classes to get a better looking code, and a easier to understand code.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use classes if you wish to, but that makes very little sense to me. What makes sense is to use dictionaries and lists:

```
words = { "gay": [ "", "", "" ],
          "hot": [ "", "", "" ]
          # add other words as necessary
        }

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    for word, emojis in words.items():
        if message.content.lower().startswith(word):
            time.sleep(1)
            for emoji in emojis:
                await message.add_reaction(emoji)
            break
```

That's the whole function, no need for hundreds of `if`s. 
**Note**: I added a `break` to exit the outer `for` loop under assumption that no word is a prefix of another, so for example there's no "hotter" in your dictionary if there's "hot" in it. If this assumption is wrong, `break` should be removed and the words  should be sorted longest-first.